# Page contents not updating when loading with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a script that uses AJAX to load certain pages of a site. The page contains information that changes depending on current time.

The problem i have come to is that when i load the page with AJAX, page contents remain the same no matter how many times i try to load it, as if it was cached somehow, but when i go to that page manually in other browser tab and just hit F5, contents of that page DO change every single time as it should be.

I am not a pro so i have no idea what causes this and how to fix it.
Any ideas how to fix this purely within the JavaScript file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET requests could be cached by the browser and IE is extremely aggressive about them. So there are different possibilities: either append some random number to the url or use POST requests.